# how to exclude some properties of object

Tags: javascript, object

I'm new in JavaScript I have this object that want to exclude 2 keys :

`"age":20` and `"university":"HCC"`.

As a result, I want to see `"name:"Sam"` and `"class":55` as the only properties in the object.

```
var b = { 
    "name":"Sam",
    "age":20,
    "university":"HCC",
    "class":55
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To exclude properties from an object, you could use a simple `delete`:

```js
var b = { 
    "name":"Sam",
    "age":20,
    "university":"HCC",
    "class":55
};

delete b.age;
delete b.university;

console.log(b);
```

If you want to check the value is the same as well, you could use `reduce` with `Object.entries`:

```js
var b = { 
    "name":"Sam",
    "age":20,
    "university":"HCC",
    "class":55
};

const res = Object.entries(b).reduce((a, [k, v]) => {
  if (!((k == "age" && v == 20) || (k == "university" && v == "HCC"))) {
    a[k] = v;
  }
  return a;
}, {});
  
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please vote to close such clear duplicate questions.

Comment: My bad, I have never seen that question before. Thanks for telling me.

Comment: thank you for helping me i was trying this in my code for some reason if item contain & or space it doesn't work. for example it doesn't delete this item: art & science

Comment: No problem @Eli, always glad to help. If my answer fixed your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Comment: You can also use the spread operator: const {age, university, ...newB} = b;

Comment: Yes @DovRine, that would also work.